# Create a box which is wider than columns?

Tags: boxes, multicol

I am using `multicolumn` to make a document wich has parts of it in two-colums and other parts which fill the whole page width. So far, everything works fine. MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,draft=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}   
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3in}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \chapter*{Chapter 1}
\end{center}
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{multicols}{2}
 \lipsum[1-8]
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Now i want to add a box or something, which includes additional information to a topic. Floating would be nice, but is not required, it can also be fixed. Sounds easy at first. But what I want to achieve is, that the box has the with of a column + a third of the other. So in general it should look someway like this:

```
    #######################
    #######################
    #######################

    ########## ############
    ########## ############
    ########## ############
    ########## ############
    ########## ############
    ###### ****************
    ###### ****************
    ###### ****************
    ###### ****************
    ###### ****************
    ########## ############
    ########## ############
```

Experimenting with something like `\parbox{1.3\columnwidth}` or `multispan` does not help.

Comment: hope wrapfig.sty is the one what you looking for, please confirm if not so...

Comment: Unfortunately not, as the box should contain text (and maybe some TikZ elements, but not a figure. Documentation of wrapfig shows that it is made basically for figures and tables.

Comment: Wrapfig is just a minipage with a figure caption.  Lose the caption and it is just a minipage.  The problem is synchronizing the two columns.  You could do it with flowfram, but you would need to manually break the paragraphs where the column widths change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a `wrapfigure` which overhangs the entire second column.  One must manually insert the blank `\parbox` into the second column in precisely the right spot (it counts as one word).

The `\vspace` was an ad hoc addition to compensate for the lack of glue caused by replacing several lines of text with one large box.  Similarly, I subtracted 1em from the width to lose the "too wide" warning.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper,draft=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage[UTF8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}   
\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\columnsep}{0.3in}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con-
sectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adi-
piscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, no-
nummy eget, consectetuer id, vulpu-
tate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue
eu neque. Pellentesque habitant mor-
bi tristique senectus et netus et male-
suada fames ac turpis egestas. Mau-
ris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus
sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum ur-
na fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tel-
 \begin{wrapfigure}{r}[\dimexpr \columnsep+\columnwidth]{1.333\columnwidth}
   \global\setbox\tempbox=\vbox{\lipsum[4]}
   \usebox{\tempbox}
 \end{wrapfigure}
lus sit amet tortor gravida placerat.
Integer sapien est, iaculis in, preti-
um quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent
eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum.
Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla,
malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac,
nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nul-
la. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis
nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan elei-
fend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget
orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

\lipsum[2]

Nulla malesuada porttitor diam.
\vspace{0pt plus 1ex minus 1ex}%
\parbox{\dimexpr \columnwidth-1em}% note the added \baselineskip for setspace
  {\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\tempbox+\dp\tempbox+2\intextsep+\baselineskip}}
Donec felis erat, congue non, vo-
lutpat at, tincidunt tristique, libe-
ro. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis.
Donec nonummy pellentesque ante.
Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Pro-
in fermentum massa ac quam. Sed di-
am turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a,
molestie nec, leo. Maecenas lacinia.
Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, ac-
cumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum. Mor-
bi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc
eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia
nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincid-
unt purus vel magna. Integer non en-
im. Praesent euismod nunc eu pu-
rus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus.
Nullam cursus pulvinar lectus. Donec
et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim.
Vestibulum pellentesque felis eu massa.

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, the example works like that. But if I add  again `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` which was part of the " irrelevant rubbish" you removed but is essential for my document, the whole thing is messed up.

Comment: Actually, the only problem is that everything got moved around the page.

Comment: `onehalfspacing` with a two-column document seems to be too much space.

Comment: ok. now i understood how the wrapfigure and the parbox work together. thanks!

Comment: @Joseph: Spacing looks fine like that. The whole text includes lots of Tikz-elements, so a lot of space is needed here.

Comment: @scienceponder, I don't know why lots of Tikz-elements depend on lots of interline space in a two-column page, but anyway...